# Prestashop - Uncaught ReferenceError: displayFlags is not defined

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I've got a problem with prestashop while trying to add some pages to block top menu - arrows adding pages not responding. 
In console we have:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: displayFlags is not defined
    at index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=d04a82c3f1df7e1137115c06fec191cc&configure=blocktopmenu&tab_module=front_office_features&module_name=blocktopmenu:1089

Uncaught ReferenceError: displayFlags is not defined
    at index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=d04a82c3f1df7e1137115c06fec191cc&configure=blocktopmenu&tab_module=front_office_features&module_name=blocktopmenu:1406
```

I've no idea what's going on

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?